# Does anyone know how to make this work it is for object orientated programming?

Tags: python, oop

The threat level is calculated correctly but the rest of the attributes are either not displayed or in the wrong order.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNsLs.png)

Here is the code if u can help me:

```
class animal():
    def __init__(self, animal_species="unknown", age=0, threat_level="peaceful", hunger_level=0): 
        
        self.animal_species = animal_species
        self.age = age
        self.hunger_level = hunger_level
        self.threat_level = threat_level

def create():
    animal_species = input("Enter species: ")
    age = int(input("Enter age: "))
    return animal(animal_species, age)

def changeThreat_level():
    hunger_level = int(input("Enter hunger(1-10): "))
    threat_level = None
    if hunger_level <= 3:
      threat_level = 'peaceful'
    elif hunger_level >=4 and hunger_level<=7:
      threat_level = 'narky'
    else:
      threat_level = 'aggressive'
    return animal(hunger_level, threat_level)


cat = create()
cat = changeThreat_level()

print("Animal's Attributes: ")
print("-------------------------")
print("The species of the animal is", cat.animal_species)
print("The age of the animal is", cat.age)
print("The animals threat level is", cat.threat_level)
print("The animals hunger out of 10 is around", cat.hunger_level)
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: You aren't modifying the levels of an existing object; you are (incorrectly) creating a *new* instance. You have to pass `cat` to `changeThreat_level` as an argument, and modifying its attributes instead.

Comment: @chepner can you explain that in a more simpler way as i'm very new to object orientated programming so im only just trying to understand how everything works

Comment: This has very little to do with object-oriented programming per se. You are simply calling `animal` with the wrong arguments in `changeThreat_level`.

Answer (score 0):

Your return in `changeThreat_level` is putting `hunger_level` and `threat_level` values where the constructor is expecting `animal_species` and `age`.
You could try specifying the fields:

```
return animal(hunger_level=hunger_level, threat_level=threat_level)
```

Better yet pass in the instance of the animal and change it's attributes.
Something like this should work:

```
class animal():
    def __init__(self, animal_species="unknown", age=0, threat_level="peaceful", hunger_level=0): 
        
        self.animal_species = animal_species
        self.age = age
        self.hunger_level = hunger_level
        self.threat_level = threat_level

def create():
    animal_species = input("Enter species: ")
    age = int(input("Enter age: "))
    return animal(animal_species, age)

def changeThreat_level(animal:animal):
    hunger_level = int(input("Enter hunger(1-10): "))
    threat_level = None
    if hunger_level <= 3:
      threat_level = 'peaceful'
    elif hunger_level >=4 and hunger_level<=7:
      threat_level = 'narky'
    else:
      threat_level = 'aggressive'
    animal.hunger_level = hunger_level
    animal.threat_level = threat_level


cat = create()
changeThreat_level(cat)

print("Animal's Attributes: ")
print("-------------------------")
print("The species of the animal is", cat.animal_species)
print("The age of the animal is", cat.age)
print("The animals threat level is", cat.threat_level)
print("The animals hunger out of 10 is around", cat.hunger_level)
```

Answer (score 0):

One of OOP principles is encapsulation, which is achieved when each object keeps its state private inside the class. Consider using getters and setters for objects manipulation. In this way you won't face this kind of problem.

Also, your identation is wrong, as `create` and `changeThreat_level` are methods of the Cat object, they must be nested below the class. Also, as the `cat` is an instance of the `animal` object consider initializing cat as the following:

```py
class animal():
    def __init__(self, animal_species="unknown", age=0, threat_level="peaceful", hunger_level=0): 
        self.animal_species = animal_species
        self.age = age
        self.hunger_level = hunger_level
        self.threat_level = threat_level

    def create(self):
        self.animal_species = input("Enter species: ")
        self.age = int(input("Enter age: "))
        self.hunger_level = int(input("Enter hunger(1-10): "))

    def change_threat_level(self):
        if self.hunger_level <= 3:
            self.threat_level = 'peaceful'
        elif self.hunger_level >=4 and self.hunger_level<=7:
            self.threat_level = 'narky'
        else:
            self.threat_level = 'aggressive'

    def print_animal_information(self):
        print("Animal's Attributes: ")
        print("-------------------------")
        print("The species of the animal is", self.animal_species)
        print("The age of the animal is", self.age)
        print("The animals threat level is", self.threat_level)
        print("The animals hunger out of 10 is around", self.hunger_level)


cat = animal()
cat.create()
cat.change_threat_level()
cat.print_animal_information()
```

Now your code works fine.